# Are these FK definitions equivalent?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, schema, ddl

Are the following two Foreign key definitions of `address` equivalent? by this I mean whether they end up with the same effective database elements (index, constraints, etc). I prefer the latter because it's a shorthand and less to type in.

Here the address index and constraint are created explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (customer_id),
  KEY idx_fk_address_id (address_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_customer_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Are the constraint and index also created here?

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (customer_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any other differences to be aware of?

Comment: I prefer the named constraint, easier to maintain when you need to disable or remove it.

Comment: Don't you get an implicitly by convention generated constraint name that you can also disable?

Comment: Yes, you will get autogenerated name, but then you need to read metadata table. Second when you are using schema compare software and database is set from scratch second time it could show it as a difference(depending on option). Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Only 65000 customers? Come on; where's your sense of ambition!!

Comment: @Strawberry LOL :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a functional standpoint, these declarations are equivalent. The difference is that the first snippet set a friendly name that would be easier to maintain later, and the second one will create some auto-generated name.